# QueryRecord adds whitespace within CASE WHEN statament

Tags: apache-nifi

I have a JSON file:

```
[ {
  "id": 1
}, {
  "id": 2
} ]
```

And attribute `ad.cost_type`. For example now it contains value 0. I want to modify JSON's based on this attribute and wrote simple SQL-like script inside `QueryRecord`:

```
SELECT
    CASE
    WHEN ${ad.cost_type} = 0 THEN 'cpc'
    WHEN ${ad.cost_type} = 1 THEN 'cpm'
    WHEN ${ad.cost_type} = 3 THEN 'ocpm'
END AS type
*
FROM FLOWFILE
```

Result is:

```
[ {
  "type" : "cpc ",
  "id": 1
}, {
  "type" : "cpc ",
  "id": 2
} ]
```

As you can see I have an extra whitespace after value from attribute and i don't understand from where it came. What did i miss?

Comment: It seems that appears as padding to the largest string. It certainly is a bug for Apache Calcite (the QueryRecord processor uses that library)